# Numeric values for strings

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

OK, I need help.

I am trying yo add label values.  Ie. buttonpLabel is = 10, rbuttonLabel =2

I was thinking I could somehow find the value for self.buttonfLabel.text and add them to self.rbuttonLabel.text.

I want to present the answer in wLabel

I just can't figure out the semantics .....

Any ideas?

J

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                      ofObject:(id)object 
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                       context:(void *)context {


    NSNumber *newValue = [change valueForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
    NSNumber *supertotals;

       //  change gives back an NSDictionary of changes


    // update the appropriate label
   if (keyPath == @"buttonf") {

        self.buttonfLabel.text = [newValue stringValue];


    }
    else if (keyPath == @"rbutton") {
        self.rbuttonLabel.text = [newValue stringValue];

    }
    else if (keyPath == @"pbutton") {
        self.pbuttonLabel.text = [newValue stringValue];

    }

   /////////////below does not work.....

 supertotals = [numberWithInt:[bbuttonLabel.text intValue]]+[numberWithInt:[buttonp Label.text intValue]];
    self.wLabel.text = [supertotals stringValue];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSNumber`'s are classes and can not be added together to produce another `NSNumber` with the new value (You may see this behavior in other languages but that is a result of operator overloading and is not supported in Objective-C). Change the code to something similar to this:

```
supertotals = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([bbuttonLabel.text intValue] + 
                                       [buttonpLabel.text intValue])];
```